# Issue when installing Laravel Valet

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet

I am trying to install Laravel Valet.

When i run the following:
composer global require laravel/valet --update-with-all-dependencies

It returns the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
- laravel/installer is locked to version v4.0.5 and an update of this package was not requested.
- laravel/installer v4.0.5 requires php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.0.1) does not satisfy that requirement.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

If someone could help me fix the above, i would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It's because, by the time I am writing this, Laravel does not support PHP 8.
You can check the pull request here,
https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/33388